# Pip: ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 5] Input/output error

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I'm trying to install the package `xformers` via pip on a remote server. But I get this error:

```
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 5] Input/output error
```

I don't know what to do! I looked at some other similar questions but non of them helped.

Comment: Could you add whole output from pip?

Comment: Can either be an actual physical disk problem or lack of permissions to read/write to the disk.

Comment: @maciek97x This is everything. I found out what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out my hard disk was full and had no space left to write on. This error was because of that.